# XML error with custom policy adding forgot password XML logic

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a working sign up or sign in Azure B2C page using a custom policy. I'm now trying to get the 'forgot password link' to work.

I've followed all steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy but when I upload the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml in 'upload custom policy' I get the error:

> Validation failed: 3 validation error(s) found in policy
> "B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS" of tenant. User journey
> "SignupOrSignin" in policy "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" of tenant
> has step 4 with 2 claims exchanges. It must be preceded by a claims
> provider selection in order to determine which claims exchange can be
> used

I thought it would be due to the code around:

`<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">`

But the sample code is the same in that section! https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/embedded-password-reset/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions_SSPR.xml

Could the issue be to do with anything in TrustFrameworkBase.xml?

Here is TrustFameworkExtensions.xml (I have swapped out the real GUIDs for the word guid to paste here):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <TrustFrameworkPolicy 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" 
    PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
    TenantId="companyname.onmicrosoft.com" 
    PolicyId="B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" 
    PublicPolicyUri="http://companyname.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions">
  
    <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>companyname.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</PolicyId>
    </BasePolicy>

    <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimType Id="identityProviderAccessToken">
      <DisplayName>Identity Provider Access Token</DisplayName>
      <DataType>string</DataType>
      <AdminHelpText>Stores the access token of the identity provider.</AdminHelpText>
    </ClaimType>
    <ClaimType Id="isForgotPassword">
      <DisplayName>Indicates whether the user selected Forgot Password</DisplayName>
      <DataType>boolean</DataType>
      <AdminHelpText>Whether the user has selected Forgot your Password</AdminHelpText>
    </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <LoadUri>urlhere</LoadUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
    </BuildingBlocks>

    <ClaimsProviders>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>

      <TechnicalProfiles>        
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <!-- MAKE SURE THESE KEYS ARE CORRECT FROM THE PORTAL -->
            <Item Key="client_id">guid</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">guid</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="guid" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="guid" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="ForgotPassword">
          <DisplayName>Forgot your password?</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isForgotPassword" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile> 
      <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </TechnicalProfile>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
      </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>companyname</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Login using companyname</DisplayName>      
    <TechnicalProfiles>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="OIDC-companyname">
          <DisplayName>Employee</DisplayName>
          <Description>Login with your Office account</Description>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
          <Metadata>
            
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">guid</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
            <!-- The key below allows you to specify each of the Azure AD tenants that can be used to sign in. Update the GUIDs below for each tenant. -->
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item>
        
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_companynameSecret"/>
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />    
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>google.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Google</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>        
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Google-OAUTH">
          <DisplayName>Google</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">google</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth</Item>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email profile</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">url</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_GoogleSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="google.com" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />            
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>          
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />          
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
    <Domain>live.com</Domain>
    <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="MSA-MicrosoftAccount-OpenIdConnect">
      <DisplayName>Microsoft Account</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://login.live.com</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.live.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">guid</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MicrosoftSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

     <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>

        <!-- Custom Restful service -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SignUp">
          <DisplayName>Validate user's input data and return loyaltyNumber claim</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <!-- VERIFY THE URL IS CORRECT TO THE DEPLOYMENT SPOT -->
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://companynameapi.azurewebsites.net/api/identity</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>            
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectid" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>        
        
      </TechnicalProfiles>

    </ClaimsProvider>

   </ClaimsProviders>

     <UserJourneys>
    
     <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
      
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MicrosoftExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="companynameExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="MicrosoftExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MSA-MicrosoftAccount-OpenIdConnect" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="companynameExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="OIDC-companyname" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <JourneyList>
    <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
  </JourneyList>
</OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>



        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
 
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
 
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>

    </UserJourneys>

<SubJourneys>
  <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
      <!-- Validate user's email address. -->
      <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>

      <!-- Collect and persist a new password. -->
      <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
    </OrchestrationSteps>
  </SubJourney>
</SubJourneys>

</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the TechnicalProfiles section of the TrustFrameworkExtensions.XML you need to make these updates

1. Replace "guid" in this line of the XML with the application ID of the **ProxyIdentity**ExperienceFramework application.

   ```
   <Item Key="client_id">guid</Item>
   ```
2. Replace "guid" in this line of the XML with the application ID of the **ProxyIdentity**ExperienceFramework application.

   ```
   <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="guid" />
   ```
3. Replace "guid" in this line of the XML with the application ID of the **Identity**ExperienceFramework application.

   ```
   <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">guid</Item>
   ```
4. Replace "guid" in this line of the XML with the application ID of the **Identity**ExperienceFramework application.

   ```
   <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="guid" />
   ```

[App registrations page showing Application (client) ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87PVp.png)

Here is the tutorial I used for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy

Comment: Sorry, I will add a note to my original post. I had swapped out the real GUID for the word guid just for posting the question here.